# SharpDX sample memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, direct2d, sharpdx

I've built this [sample](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/tree/master/StoreApp/XAML%20SurfaceImageSource%20DirectX%20interop%20sample) against the SharpDX 3.0 dev binaries.

When I run it and click the various options, the memory used continually increases, from 19 to 30MB and going. Such a simple app should not be consuming so much memory.

I took a look at the code and can't find anything obvious - the easiest suspects are correctly wrapped in `using`'s, etc.

Is there a memory leak here?

Comment: That is not really conclusive evidence since the runtime uses a garbage collector, therefore memory usage will keep increasing until the garbage collector decides to collect. The collection itself is not cheap, so it will not run unless necessary.

Comment: I do see occasional decreases, which I assume to be the GC at work. But over time the memory keeps growing. So I'm led to believe that it isn't the GC, but rather objects that are not being released. Also, most of this sample uses the SharpDX interop layer into COM, which is not garbage collected. The only general requirement is that SharpDX objects should be disposed correctly.

Comment: Well I just skimmed through it quickly, but seems like `Scenario1Drawing` in `Scenario1.xaml.cs` is not disposed. The class `Scenario1ImageSource `, which is the type of `Scenario1Drawing` also subscribes to an event on static instance `Application.Current.Suspending`, that needs to be explicitly unsubscribed.